# Plotly: Add text to figure

Tags: python, r, plotly

this is an extension of the question [plotly: How to add text to existing figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716521/plotly-how-to-add-text-to-existing-figure)

I know that this method works, but is there any way to make the html page extend if you add a lot of text? I wanna write down statistics, infos etc. underneath the plot, but the page simply ends at some point. This gets even worse with a rangeslider underneath the plot. I just want to be able to scroll down and see all the info.

I hope that someone has an easy solution for this problem (other than not writing it under the plot).